# How to fix any design like 'pattern' on Design model at specific location like how we see shortcut keys at top of the model

Tags: eyeshot

So what I want is an orientation functionality, and that will look like a small compass at the bottom of the model view, it will always remain visible and fixed at that location and only work when the user double clicks on it.
I can create the design for the compass but I don't know how to get it affixed at a location.

Thank you for any suggestions or help.   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw4Dr.png/), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvvuW.png/), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qoagf.png/)

Comment: Please, share a picture or a short video showing your goal

Comment: just added few pics to show the desired output, in these pics you can see the Compass remain affixed but when double clicked it is editable and is used to set direction.